# Merge Multiple FDF docs FDFEmbedAndClose

Tags: asp-classic, fdf

I have a legacy application that uses Acrobat PDF TK to create FDF from a template PDF.

The application works fine for creating a single FDF at a time, the issue is we need to batch process multiple FDF at once, I tried with no luck using `FDFEmbedAndClose` which based on the documentation should embed FDF into a container FDF.

How should I do this?

Comment: Can you please show us the relevant code you have so far?  That is much more likely to get you help.  Also a link to the documentation you are referring would help

Comment: Also read a thread here.  https://forums.adobe.com/thread/302588?start=0&tstart=0   That basically says, no it is not possible.

Comment: Thx dijkgraaf, I ended up using PDFTk (https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) to flatten and merge the generated docs into one doc.